# The right way to compare function argument with callback function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am confused with how Python compares two objects. The code that makes things confusing is roughly like that:

```py
class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

   def __init__(self):
      super(Window,self).__init__()
      uic.loadUi('window.ui', self)
      self.show()

   def thread_it(self, func_to_execute):
      worker = Worker(func_to_execute)

      if func_to_execute == self.mpositioner.movetostart:
          worker.signals.progress.connect(self.create_raw_log_line)

      self.threadpool.start(worker)
      return worker
```

What is confusing is that the code works only if the line reading `if func_to_execute == self.mpositioner.movetostart` uses the `==` operator. When using with `is` operator it doesn't work. I was trying the `is` approach after it was suggested by VSCode Pylint, but Ruff linter doesn't complain about the `==`.

So the question would be: is there any particular reason why the `is` doesn't work?

EDIT:

I made the test using [suggested callback_test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78026106/12191020) and the result is the following:

```
callback: <bound method MotorPositioner.movetostart of <__main__.MotorPositioner object at 0x000001B81B7C60E0>>
callback id: 1890339656832
callback_fun: <bound method MotorPositioner.movetostart of <__main__.MotorPositioner object at 0x000001B81B7C60E0>>
callback_fun id: 1890339659712
Yup same function
```

Comment: *is* means it's the same object. *==* means it's equal (however equality is determined). If A *is* B then you can assert that A == B but not *vice versa*

Comment: Yes, I agree on that. I just don't "feel" it for function which is supposed to be the same object when passed as an argument. Or maybe it is not supposed?

Comment: @CtrlZ note, even that implication is not guaranteed in that direction. Indeed,  `A == B` *need not even return a `bool`*. But even when it does, even for simple types in the standard libary, it is not guaranteed. `x = float('nan'); print(x is x, x == x)` (which notoriously makes `float('nan')` break a lot of things, like hash-based containers, although, it is always quetsionable to use floats as keys in hash-based containers)

Comment: @RadekD you are working with bound-method objects, which are created on the fly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is how methods in Python work. Briefly<sup>†</sup>:

A method is just a function that exists in the namespace of a class, that when it is accessed through an *instance* of the class, returns a *bound method* which is a callable that effectively *partially applies the instance to the first positional argument to the original function* i.e. it provides the `self` parameter (which is just the name we conventionally give to the first positional parameter of a method) with the instance as an argument.

So, consider:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def bar(self):
...         print("barring", self)
...
>>> Foo.bar
<function Foo.bar at 0x111e16fc0>
```

When accessed on the class itself, it just returns the function object. Note, here, it is always going to be the case that you get the *same object* back, just the one that was created in the body of the class definition statement.

```
>>> Foo.bar is Foo.bar # this will always be True
True
```

But if we create an instance, we get a different kind of objet:

```
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.bar
<bound method Foo.bar of <__main__.Foo object at 0x11026cad0>>
>>> type(Foo.bar), type(foo.bar)
(<class 'function'>, <class 'method'>)
>>> foo.bar()
barring <__main__.Foo object at 0x11026cad0>
```

Appreciate again, that when accessed through the class, it is just the regular function you defined before, it works just like any function defined anywhere else, it simply exists in the class namespace:

```
>>> Foo.bar(42)
baring 42
>>> def baz(self):
...     print("bazzing", self)
...
>>> baz(42)
bazzing 42
```

Note, a bound-method object is created *every time you access the object through the instance*. So the following will always be evaluate to `False`:

```
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.bar is foo.bar # will always be false
False
```

Note, however, that bound-method objects will be *equal* if they are binding the **same instance** to the **same function**. So:

```
>>> foo1 = Foo()
>>> foo2 = Foo()
>>> foo1.bar == foo1.bar # always True
True
>>> foo1.bar == foo2.bar # always False
False
```

Additionally, these are introspect-able:

```
>>> foo.bar.__self__
<__main__.Foo object at 0x11026cad0>
>>> foo.bar.__func__
<function Foo.bar at 0x110250180>
```

**A quick gotcha**:

If you are following along in a REPL, you may do something like the following, trying to verify that the claims I'm making are true. And you do this reasonable test:

```
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> for _ in range(5):
...     print(id(foo.bar))
...
4581348032
4581348032
4581348032
4581348032
4581348032
```

"Huh?" You might ask. "What is going on here, why am I getting the same id's for purportedly different bound method objects? But when I check directly"

```
>>> foo.bar is foo.bar
False
```

What is going on above is that the bound method gets *reclaimed immediately after it is called because it isn't referenced anywhere*. Since it is reclaimed, it's lifetime doesn't overlap, so the `id` doesn't guaratnee that they are distinct objects. This is because in CPython, the `id` is merely the value of the PyObject pointer, that is, the memory address of the object on the privately managed heap. This heap will re-use that memory happily. But if you keep a reference around, it is not reclaimed, so it is forced to use another one:

```
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> for _ in range(5):
...     bound_method = foo.bar
...     print(id(bound_method))
...
4581907008
4581530752
4581907008
4581530752
4581907008
```

You can see a similar phenomenon with this example:

```
>>> id(object()) == id(object())
True
>>> object() is object()
False
>>> obj1 = object()
>>> obj2 = object()
>>> id(obj1) == id(obj2)
False
```

Moral of the story here is that you should be careful when using `id`.

---

† <sub>if you really want to know how this happens, then you need to understand descriptors. The [Descriptor HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) goes into the nitty-gritty details, and is worth a read in its entirety. Descriptors are used all over by Python to implement core features.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

This is basically down to a "curiosity" in Python when doing memory optimization.

`is` compare the memory address. But this is not promised to be the same for the two function objects. However for equal it checks the value (the function object) not the underlying references. Therefore `==` will always work, but `is` may or may not work.

You can play a little bit around with it using `id` which prints the memory address of the objects.

Below is a small example that prints the memory addresses using `id` and uses `is` and `==` and prints if the comparison went well or not. Note, that the example below only means to show case the usage of `id`, as the `is` comparison here is most likely to work

```py
def callback_fun() -> None:

    print(x)


def callback_test(callback: any) -> None:

    print(f'callback: {callback}')
    print(f'callback id: {id(callback)}')
    print(f'callback_fun: {callback_fun}')
    print(f'callback_fun id: {id(callback_fun)}')

    callback_id = id(callback)
    callback_fun_id = id(callback_fun)

    if callback_id == callback_fun_id:
        print('Memory address is the same')

    
    if callback is callback_fun:
        print('This time it is the same memory address')

    if callback == callback_fun:
        print('Yup same function')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    callback_test(callback_fun)
```

You can try and add similar id prints to your code.

Comment: I made the test. The results are in the EDIT section of my original question. So I understand now that because they do not actually point to the same memory address, this is the reason why IS is not working here.

Comment: This feels rather misleading. It prints *"This time it is the same memory address"*, even though that will be the case **every** time with this program.

Comment: Look at my edits in the original question. No such situation using his code.

Comment: @KellyBundy thank you for bringing this to my attention I expanded the description of the purpose of the example and how it was meant to showcase the usage of `id` and not a fully fledge example of the problem :)

Comment: I'm not sure what this code is supposed to demonstrates vis a vis `is` vs `==`. You aren't really explaining what is going on here, just gesturing towards a "memory optimization", but I don't know what you are referring to. There is no memory optimization that explains the OP's results -- quite the opposite, in fact, it is explained by an situation where the runtime is quite careless with wasting extra memory.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have removed the memory optimization part as I cannot find the presentation where I was taught that part.

Comment: I must agree that @juanpa.arrivillaga gave most detailed answer which leads even further in understanding the topic, so I selected his answer as the answer.

Comment: @RadekD I 100% agree the answer is better :)

Comment: Also @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you for the more in-depth answer I definitely learned something from it :)